# SSIS Excel connection credentials

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, ssis

There's a file stored in SharePoint that I want to use as data source in my SSIS package that will be run by SQL Server Agent.

The SQL Server Agent uses an account that doesn't have access to this file, so I want the Excel connection to use different login credentials (you can specify them in OLEDB connections). Is there any way to do this?

I know that the simplest way would be to just grant the permissions to the account that SQL Server Agent uses, but our responsible person is away. Changing the credentials in SQL Server Configuration Manager is not an option.

MS SQL Server 2008R2, Server Integration Services Version 10.50.1600.1,   Sharepoint2010,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a proxy account that has the appropriate permissions to the location of the excel file and then set the job to run as that proxy account. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190698%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396